# How to send mailt without authentication using nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer, nodejs-stream

I tried to send mail without authentication but its throwing error how to achieve it.

**mail.js**

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                service: 'gmail',
                auth: {
                  user: params.email,
                }
              });

              var mailOptions = {
                from: 'techardors@gmail.com',
                to: params.email,
                subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
                text: 'That was easy!'
              };

              transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
                if (error) {
                  console.log(error);
                } else {
                  console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
                }
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

- You have to be authenticate to send an email. So it can show where the email is coming from and similar stuff. This also applies when using **nodemailer** to send emails. You can only send an email using **nodemailer** if you are athenticated. And this is because email services tries to avoid spam to users in every way posible.

Comment: Is it posiible to remove auth to send mail using node mailer

Comment: No its not posible.

Comment: It any another framework using without auth send mail using node js